If $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)=0$ but $f''''(x_0)>0$, then $x_0$ is local minimum of $f$?
Let $f$ be a function such that all derivatives $f^{(k)}(x)$ exist around $x_0$.
Suppose in addition that $f'(x_0)=f''(x_0)=f'''(x_0)=0$ but $f''''(x_0)>0$. Can we deduce that $x_0$ is local minimum of $f$?

Yes. Use Taylor’s theorem: $f(x)=f(x_0)+\frac{f^{(4)}(x_0)}{4!}(x-x_0)^4+R_4(x)$, where $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\frac{R_4(x)}{(x-x_0)^4}=0$. This generalizes to higher derivative tests.

Thanks "twirlywoos" ...

According to Taylor's Theorem, if $f$ is 4 times differentiable in an interval $(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)$, then for every $|h|<\varepsilon$,
$$
f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+hf'(x_0)+\frac{h^2f''(x_0)}{2!}+\frac{h^3f'''(x_0)}{3!}+\frac{h^4f''''(x_0)}{4!}+r_4(x_0,h)h^4,
$$
with $\lim_{h\to 0}r_4(x_0,h)=0$. In Our case
$$
f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+\frac{h^4f''''(x_0)}{4!}+r_4(x_0,h)h^4,
$$
and as $\lim_{h\to 0}r_4(x_0,h)=0$, then for $|h|$ sufficiently small and nonzero,
$$
\frac{h^4f''''(x_0)}{4!}+r_4(x_0,h)h^4=h^4\left(\frac{f''''(x_0)}{4!}+r_4(x_0,h)\right)>0,
$$
and hence $f(x_0+h)>f(x_0)$.

Why is the remainder term $r_4(h)h^4$ contains no $x_0$?

@NoChance Yes, it does depend on $x_0$.
